# .htaccess: "redirect permanent" with fallback to a "RewriteRule"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have a webshop where we switch the subdirectory. From "/shop" to the root "/". Also some Product- and category-names change.

I want to redirect some specific URLs to newer ones. For Example:
`www.domainname.de/shop/product_abc` to `www.domainname.de/product_abc_v2`
For this, I use the `Redirect Permanent` declaration in the .htaccess File.

In the next Step I want a Fallback for all other URL´s which looks like this:
`www.domainname.de/shop/XXXXX`.

So i write this Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shop/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainname.de/ [r=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

**Now my problem**: I put the Rewrite Rule to the bottom of the .htaccess File so that the `Redirect Permanent`-Code would be used before the Rewrite Rule is used. But anyway the Rewrite Rule is always taken. Is there any solution for this problem?!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you’re mistaken in assuming that the order of these directives in the .htaccess influences the order in which they are evaluated. And you could of course simply solve this by using a `RewriteRule` instead of `Redirect` for those redirects as well.

Comment: Can you show your complete .htaccess?

Comment: @CBroe thank´s. also @Jon Lin answer this solution. To write everthing with the `RewriteRule` solved my problem. But I more likley to use the easier syntax from the mod_alias directives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use only mod_rewrite. When you mix mod_alias (`Redirect Permanent`) and mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) directives together, both modules will get applied to every URL, and in cases where both get applied, you end up with some unexpected behavior.

The first thing you need to do is change the `Redirect` to `Rewrite`:

```
Redirect Permanent /shop/product_abc /shop/product_abc_v2
```

to:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/product_abc(.*)$ /shop/product_abc_v2$1 [L,R=301]
```

Then you need to make sure the new rule is in the right place. The order matters with rewrite rules.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I prefer to use the easier syntax like the mod_alias (Redirect Permanent). But know i understand why this can´t work. Thanks for this quick help! :) i edit my .htaccess, put the code in the right place and voilà it work´s finde :)