# .htaccess redirect /foo.html to newsite.com/foo/ - redirect .html to wordpress post styled url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Edit: **Problem solved, see comment.** Original Post: I need to redirect **/foo.html** to **newsite.com/foo/** because the new site is build in wordpress, using /page/-style permalinks.

I've tried to map the old pages in .htaccess like

```
Redirect 301 /foo.html http://www.newsite.com/foo/
```

but they resolve to

```
http://www.newsite.com/foo.html?q=foo.html
```

giving a 404 error.

Is there anything wrong with my syntax?

Comment: You gave me the hint: I had to **comment out** obsolete **rewrite rules** in .htaccess which had been in place for SEO-friendly URLs with the CMS used on the old site. I thought apache would exit .htaccess after a matching redirect rule, - that obviously was not the case. It works now. Thanks, and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Using Redirect I needed to comment out all Rewrite commands. Redirect and Rewrite should not been combined as I've learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969658/htaccess-redirect-permanent-with-fallback-to-a-rewriterule).

(2) Using Redirect was not best practice for mapping pages from an old site to a new one, because I couldn't provide a fallback. Therefore, I switched over to Rewrite statements:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
# mapping old pages to new site:
RewriteRule ^page.html$ http://www.newsite.de/page/ [R=301,L]
#...some more statements like the above
# last one, fallback:
RewriteRule .* http://www.newsite.de/ [R=301,L]
```

...just in case sombody else stumbles upon my question